# An IncrediBuild distributed job cannot be started from within another distributed job

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4, incredibuild

I am trying to compile my Visual Studio 2019 code but I get this error (UE 4.22.1):

> 1>EXEC : Fatal error : An IncrediBuild distributed job cannot be started from within another distributed job.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(44,5): error MSB3075: The command "C:\unreal\UE_4.22\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat coding Win64 Development -Project="C:\unreal\coding\coding\coding.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

What this error mean and how to fix ?

Comment: You chose the wrong error. `Fatal error : An IncrediBuild distributed job cannot be started from within another distributed job` is the problem. The second error was caused by the result of the first. **Fatal error** is relevant. If you have a process that depends on another process to succeed first, and the first one fails, the second must fail too due to the dependency. The error message also clearly tells you it's an Incredibuild problem (`Fatal error: An Incredibuild distributed job`), so your update is not meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the solution and rebuilding fixed the issue for me.
I think the problem lied with how the makefiles were generated on my workstation. Somehow, they were generated in such a way that Incredibuild would be called twice.